# how can I delete rows with same column in hbase table?

Tags: hive, hbase

I have an Hbase table with 6 columns created using Hive and loaded with data. I need to delete the rows which have the same data in that particular column. I need a HQL command for that.

Here are my table columns:

```
firstname    lastname    location    id    address    description
```

I want to delete the rows with same **description**.

Comment: please share some of what you already did to try and resolve this issue, any query that you tried and didn't work, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DELETE is available starting in Hive 0.14.
Deletes can only be performed on tables that support ACID. See Hive Transactions for details.

As for your query try something like

```
DELETE
FROM TABLE
WHERE TABLE.a IN (SELECT foo FROM B);
```

OR

```
DELETE
FROM T1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT B FROM T2 WHERE T1.X = T2.Y)
```